# When I output a string into a checked list box in windows forms only the first line of the string is shown next to the checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

When I click the button method below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;

        //Concatenate the text value of the 3 text boxes
        output = "Task: " + this.textBoxTask.Text + "\r\n";
        output += "Description: " + this.textBoxDescription.Text + "\r\n";
        output += "Due Date: " + this.textBoxDueDate.Text + "\r\n";

        this.checkedListBoxTasks.Items.Add(output);

    }
```

On the line 'Task: whatever i wrote in the textbox' is shown next to the checkbox is there anyway to make it show the other two lines?

Comment: Have a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213792/top-left-box-alignment-on-a-multi-line-checkbox-with-a-large-font

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharpgeneral/thread/30e9fdb9-9bfa-4807-a79b-0d05f69454ae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
this.checkedListBoxTasks.Items.Add(this.textBoxTask.Text);
this.checkedListBoxTasks.Items.Add(this.textBoxDescription.Text);
this.checkedListBoxTasks.Items.Add(this.textBoxDueDate.Text);
```

Hope this help you. :D

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the **StringBuilder Class** in the **System.Text namespace** for string concatening.

Comment: -1 Is a comment since it doesn't help OP to answer his question.